# Select que cargue los elementos al momento de abrir la pagina

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un select que es dinámico, al momento de abrir la pagina realiza su función pero lo que requiero es que cuando abra la pagina esté seleccionado el valor por defecto y me arroje la imágenes del valor seleccionado, ya que es molestoso abrir la página y no ver nada hasta seleccionar el valor.

PHP:

```
include '../conexion.php';
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM mantras_productos ORDER BY tipo_producto ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$producto.="<option value='0'>Selecciona Un Producto</option>";
while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $producto.= "<option value='".$f['id_producto']."'>".$f['tipo_producto']."</option>";    
}
echo $producto;
```

Javascript:

```
$(nombreProdu());
function nombreProdu(busquedaProdu)
{
  $.ajax({
    url:'admin/phpadmin/selectProductos.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'html',
    data : {busquedaProdu: busquedaProdu},
  })

  .done(function(result){
    $("#cbx_carrito").html(result);
  })
}

$(document).ready(function(){     
    $("#cbx_carrito").change(function () {
        $("#cbx_carrito option:selected").each(function () {
            id_producto = $(this).val();
            $.get("php/carritoproductos.php", { id_producto: id_producto }, function(data){
                $("#cargaCarrito").html(data);
            });            
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En el momento en que preparas las opciones a mostrar es cuando puedes marcar una como seleccionada:

```
if (esProductoPorDefecto()) {
    $producto.= "<option selected value='".$f['id_producto']."'>".$f['tipo_producto']." /option>"; 
} else {
    $producto.= "<option value='".$f['id_producto']."'>".$f['tipo_producto']." /option>"; 
}
```

Donde esProductoPorDefecto() es la condición que tú determines para seleccionar el producto por defecto, que bien podría ser el primero de la lista